# How to retrieve parent document based on subdocument values in Mongoose?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema's:

```
var Child = new mongoose.Schema({
    'field': String,
    'value': String
  });

var Parent = new mongoose.Schema({
    'name': String,
    'children': [ Child ]
  });
```

I want to return the `Parent` for which one of the `Child`'s corresponds to the following JSON object:

```
{ 'field': 'Family Name', 'value': 'Smith' }
```

I have tried this:

```
Parent.findOne({ 'children': { 'field': 'Family Name', 'value': 'Smith' } }, fn ...)
```

but it keeps on retrieving `null`.

**EDIT:**

Testing through the Mongo shell extension, I found out that the `Child` sub-documents have their own `_id`'s. If I add that `_id` to the query, it fetches the `parent` document. Now, I don't know in advance what that child `id` will be. So: how can I remove it from the sub-document query? (In other words, the above query literally looks for a JSON object with only two properties, while the sub-documents have three)

My environment is: Node.js, Mongoose, MongoDB

Comment: If you have the child object you can call `child.parent()`. If you don't, then yes you'll need to query for it.

Comment: I don't have the `child` object, hence the query. But the query itself does not seem to be fetching any `parent`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems the `$elemMatch` is the query operator to solve this problem. The actual query should be written as follows:

```
Parent.findOne({ 'children': { $elemMatch: { 'field': 'Family Name', 'value': 'Smith' } } }, fn ...)
```

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to make $elemMatch work on a sub-sub-sub-document. have you tried anything like that?

Answer (score 5):

Is there a reason you use field, value structure on the child documents? It would be easier to simply use the key as the field, like `{"FamilyName": "Smith"}`. This would allow something like:

```
Parent.findOne({'children.FamilyName': 'Smith'}, function(err, doc){...});
```

Comment: Indeed, but I have a dynamic model therefore the somewhat extended structure. In the meantime, I found the solution; will post it in a second